# How can I push objects to arrays with similar names?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object

I have a form that I can create duplicate sections. Right now when the form is submitted the form spits out one giant object. I'm working on a filter function that can filter out the duplicate sections and organize the duplicates in array so it works with my API.

e.g.

// base object

```
  {
    question_10: ""
    question_10a: ""
    question_11_checkbox: false
    question_11_checkbox_copy_0: false
    question_11_checkbox_copy_1: true
    question_11_text: "110 Monroe St"
    question_11_text_copy_0: "186 Aspen Road"
    question_12_checkbox: false
    question_12_checkbox_copy_0: false
    question_12_text: "New York"
    question_12_text_copy_0: "South Orange"
    ...
  }
```

// what I want is

```
{
  question_10: ""
  question_10a: ""
  question_11_checkbox: false
  question_11_checkbox_copies: [
    { question_11_checkbox_copy_0: false } 
    { question_11_checkbox_copy_1: true }
  ]
  question_11_text: "101 Monroe St"
  question_11_text_copies: [
    { question_11_text_copy_0: "186 Aspen Road"}
  ]
  question_12_checkbox: false
  question_12_checkbox_copies: [
    { question_12_checkbox_copy_0: false}
  ]
  question_12_text: "New York"
  question_12_text_copies: [
    { question_12_text_copy_0: "South Orange"}
  ]

   ...
 }
```

So far I've been able to filter out the copies from the original object and create the arrays for the copies

```
 // filter out copy keys
const copiesKey = Object.keys(data).filter(key => key.includes('copy'));

const copy = {};

// create arrays for copies
copiesKey.map(copiedQuestion => {

  if (!(`${copiedQuestion.slice(0, copiedQuestion.length - 7)}_copies` in copy)) {
    copy[`${copiedQuestion.slice(0, copiedQuestion.length - 7)}_copies`] = [];
  }
});
```

Where I'm stuck is it's not clear how to match the object to the appropriate array and push it.
e.g.

```
question_11_text_copies: [
  { question_11_text_copy_0: "186 Aspen Road" }
]
```

So far I've tried to slice the last three keys of the copy_0 object and match the key to the array name by using array.filter, but that didn't work as expected.

How can I match the 'copy_n' objects to the appropriate array and push those objects to the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a bit old fashioned, but using a [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop in combination with regex pattern matching against the key might be the clearest solution.

```js
const data = {
  question_10: "",
  question_10a: "",
  question_11_checkbox: false,
  question_11_checkbox_copy_0: false,
  question_11_checkbox_copy_1: true,
  question_11_text: "110 Monroe St",
  question_11_text_copy_0: "186 Aspen Road",
  question_12_checkbox: false,
  question_12_checkbox_copy_0: false,
  question_12_text: "New York",
  question_12_text_copy_0: "South Orange",
};

const copy_n = /^(.*)_copy_(\d+)$/;
const result = {};
for (const key in data) {
  const value = data[key];
  const match = key.match(copy_n);
  
  if (match) {
    const copies_key = `${match[1]}_copies`;
    const index = parseInt(match[2], 10);
    result[copies_key] ||= [];
    result[copies_key][index] = { [key]: value };
  } else {
    result[key] = value;
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

The pattern `/^(.*)_copy_(\d+)$/` matches anything that ends with `_copy_` followed by 1 or more decimals. Everything before `_copy_` is placed in capture group 1, the decimals behind `_copy_` are placed in capture group 2.

If there is no match (*else* scenario) we simply assign the value to the same key.

If there is a match (*if* scenario) we first determine the collection key (`copies_key`) and the index to use. We then check if `result[copies_key]` is already set (we check if it's a truthy value to be precise). If it's not, we assign it to an empty array. After that we use the `index` to assign an object to the correct index in the array.

Comment: Thank you. I changed your for in loop to Object.keys.forEach and used camelCase for the variables, but otherwise works great!

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce to object's entries to a new object. For each key find if it has a base key (the one before "*copy*") using a RegExp with lookahead. If it doesn't has a base key, add it directly to the accumulator. If it does, add it to the appropriate "copies" array (initialize it if needed using Logical nullish assignment `??=`) ([TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9#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)).

```js
const fn = obj => Object.entries(obj)
  .reduce((acc, [k, v]) => {
    const [baseKey] = k.match(/.*(?=_copy_)/) ?? [] // get the key from an item with copy
  
    if(!baseKey) acc[k] = v // if no baseKey add the item to the accumulator
    else {
      const copiesKey = `${baseKey}_copies`
      acc[copiesKey] ??= [] // if no copies key add a new one to the accumulator    
      acc[copiesKey].push({ [k]: v }) // create an object and push to the current copies key
    }
    
    return acc
  }, {})

const obj = {"question_10":"","question_10a":"","question_11_checkbox":false,"question_11_checkbox_copy_0":false,"question_11_checkbox_copy_1":true,"question_11_text":"110 Monroe St","question_11_text_copy_0":"186 Aspen Road","question_12_checkbox":false,"question_12_checkbox_copy_0":false,"question_12_text":"New York","question_12_text_copy_0":"South Orange"}
const result = fn(obj)

console.log(result)
```